# FX6 and "ERC-20 Block Link Fee" or My Funds are being held Hostage

Tags: erc-20, fees

I was "tricked" into using FX6/Sundell, but that is a story for another thread.

I was able to move my funds out of FX6/Sundell into my Coinbase Wallet. But, it appears FX6/Sundell were able get my account "restricted" so I cannot touch my Coinbase Wallet funds. I contacted CS at FX6 and was told I need to pay a "ERC-20 Block Link Fee" of $37,800.00 before they will unfreeze my account. This fee amounts to 5% of the Funds I have in my account.

I contacted Coinbase and was told my account was "restricted" because I tried to send money to a "blacklisted" account.  According to my account, no transfers were made on the date Coinbase said the offending transfer was made.

Coinbase advised that **its** restriction will be lifted on May 29, 2023 (60 days from the date of the alleged offending transfer). At this point in time, I am waiting it out.

Any input or shared experience will be helpful

Comment: There is no question here.

Comment: I Have been Trying To Get money out of my FX6 account. Now It’s Frozen An Every Time I Get Connected To CS . I Wait For Over 15 Minutes An Have To Try Again After That It Shows I Have No Reception To Contact Them ??? Sounds Like A serious Scam !!!!

Comment: Do you send the funds to USDT? Or which coin do you send it to, mine keep failing

Answer (score 0):

I am having the exact same issue.
A romance scam.
I have about 50k real money in there.  Over 187k fake money in there.

I found out how they do it.
They change your password, logon as you, extract real money, post a fake amount.

Next time you login, your password does not work and you have to run thru the forgot password.

Then customer support ghosts you, or cuts you off.